# Base64 decoding in Javascript missing some characters that were decoded correctly in c++

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm trying to decode a string received from the web - I have a C++ code that decodes a base64 and I've replicated this code in JS but I get a slightly different response - Its important to mention that the C++ response is the one I need...

The string to decode is:

> aXI4YlB5V2xshfYcsai4DYKFqLTn0KJDk0TTOzNwgKBlyfD7bvnSHuxzICs+ubUyoypzWSZK/vVDEMr+uHw8Of41OESh25ZfRAibxe7zyV+gSTFHBCaCryeb26KjVY6LretgDIWafd+Vvn/iw9aWGr9lT8ZMHY7KX3/Mk1O5I9BHnDiipZAegyp3r6x6yJYIgbYr08gbLD0Chjbkc6BzKhLc6/XK1g==

the response I need to get is :

> ir8bPyWll…ö±¨¸
>   ‚…¨´çÐ¢C“DÓ;3p€ eÉðûnùÒìs +>¹µ2£*sY&JþõCÊþ¸|<9þ58D¡Û–*D›ÅîóÉ* I1G&‚¯'›Û¢£UŽ‹­ë`…š}ß•¾âÃÖ–¿eOÆLŽÊ_Ì“S¹#ÐGœ8¢¥ƒ*w¯¬zÈ–¶+ÓÈ,=†6äs s*ÜëõÊÖ

Instead I get:

> ir8bPyWllö±¨¸
>   ¨´çÐ¢CDÓ;3p eÉðûnùÒìs +>¹µ2£*sY&JþõCÊþ¸|<9þ58D¡Û_DÅîóÉ_ I1G&¯'Û¢£U­ë`}ß¾âÃÖ¿eOÆLÊ_ÌS¹#ÐG8¢¥*w¯¬zÈ¶+ÓÈ,=6äs s*ÜëõÊÖ

They are very similar except for specific characters:
Instead of ‚… I get ¨´ and several other small differences - What can cause this differentiation?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should edit your post to include the code here.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like some kind of encoding issue while *showing* the content you decoded.
If you received valid encoded data, then I don't see why you'd get wrong decoded data.

Comment: I manage to display both strings - Maybe it has something to do with the C++ handling the text as unsigned Char while javascript doesn't? onine decoder/encoder such as http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Encode/Default.aspx managed to do the conversion properly while javascript based ones like mine have the same bugs

Comment: Can't say. How did you managed to get the same result? What did you changed?

Comment: I didn't change anything - when I input the string to decode in their online converter I get the same binary I get for the C++ code I have - If I use my Javascript or any other online javascript base converter I get the slightly different version...